# Как вывести массив из базы в двумерный массив в PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Добрый день/вечер у в базе есть 570 записей 
пример (p_id, test_id, test_row, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3)

дамп вывода

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p_id] => 1
            [test_id] => 1
            [test_row] => 1
            [answer_1] => +
            [answer_2] => +
            [answer_3] => -
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [p_id] => 2
            [test_id] => 1
            [test_row] => 2
            [answer_1] => +
            [answer_2] => +
            [answer_3] => +
        )
     ....

    [570] => Array
        (
            [p_id] => 3
            [test_id] => 1
            [test_row] => 3
            [answer_1] => +
            [answer_2] => +
            [answer_3] => o
        )
```

Как мне превратить этот дамп в json формат такого вида

```
{
    test_id_1: {
        row_1: {
            a: +,
            b: o,
            c: -,
        }
        row_2: {
            a: +,
            b: +,
            c: -,
        }
        row_3: {
            a: o,
            b: o,
            c: +,
        }
    }, 
    test_id_38: {
        row_1: {
            a: -,
            b: -,
            c: +,
        }
        row_2: {
            a: +,
            b: +,
            c: -,
        }
        row_3: {
            a: +,
            b: o,
            c: +,
        }
    }
}
```

test_id должен соответсвовать таковому из базы данных

я пытался делать два цикла, но вообще запутался, что и как?

Comment: часть `a: 1, b: 2, c:3` постоянная, или что?

Comment: это разные ответы.  всего 38 тестов по 15 ячеек в каждой ячейке  три ответа

Comment: я в вашем примере вижу что эти значения постоянно повторяются. объясните на конкретном примере, что и откуда берется.

Comment: обновил, просто хотел показать как структура должна выглядеть

Comment: пытаюсь вот так, но не получается не на думать почему, то 

function output_json($db) {

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM answers ORDER by p_id ";

 $r = $db->execute_query($sql);

 $result = $r['result']->fetchAll();


 for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { 
  
  for ($j=0; $j < count($result[$i+1]); $j++) { 
   $myResult[$i+1][$j] = array("a" => $result[$i+1][$j], 
  }

 }


 //header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 //echo json_encode($result);
 die();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для начала получите все `test_id` из исходного массива:

```
$ids = array_column($data, 'test_id');
```

Далее возьмите уникальные id, и сгенерируйте ключи для нового массива

```
$keys = array_map(function($id){ return "test_id_$id";}, array_unique($ids));
```

и сформируйте массив с такими ключами и пустыми массивами в качестве значений

```
$result = array_fill_keys($keys, []);
```

Теперь проходите по массиву, и обрабатывайте `rows`. Что-то вроде такого:

```
foreach($data as $v){
    $tkey = "test_id_{$v['test_id']}";
    $rkey = "row_{$v['test_row']}";

    $result[$tkey][$rkey] = [
          'a' => $v['answer_1'],
          'b' => $v['answer_2'],
          'c' => $v['answer_3'] 
      ];
}
```

что то вроде такого.

*зы: Код не проверялся*

Comment: ну у меня test_id повторяется 15 раз потому, что в каждом тесте 15 вопросов ?

Comment: @MixmaxMakster откуда мне знать что у вас там повторяется и сколько раз. возьмите приведенный код и проверьте его на каждом шаге. я его не проверял, писал прямо тут.

Comment: ок все работает!